# how to close my menu item when click in mobile menu

Tags: reactjs

*I have a menu already and the issue is, its not closing once i click on menu list item in mobile*

const [menuActive, setMenuActive] = useState(null);

```
const handleMenuActive = () => {
    setMenuActive(!menuActive);
    
  };
```

*This is the code*

```
                        {
                            menus.map((data,idx) => (
                                <li key={idx} onClick={()=> handleDropdown(idx)} className={`menu-item ${data.namesub ? 'menu-item-has-children' : ''} ${activeIndex === idx ? 'active' : ''}`} 
                                
                                >
                                    <Link to={data.links}>{data.name}</Link>
                                    {
                                        data.namesub &&
                                        <ul className="sub-menu">
                                            {
                                                data.namesub.map((submenu) => (
                                                    <li key={submenu.id} className="menu-item"><NavLink to={submenu.links}>{submenu.sub}</NavLink></li>
                                                ))
                                            }
                                        </ul>
                                    }
                                    
                                </li>
                            ))
                        }
                        {/* <Link to = '/my-acc'>
                             <li className='menu-item '> My acc</li>
                        </Link> */}
                    </ul>
                    
                </nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use functional updates:

```
const [menuActive, setMenuActive] = useState(false);
setMenuActive(preMenuActive => !preMenuActive)
```

[useState functional updates](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#functional-updates)